# Numpy power ufunc operating on specific axis

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I find it weird that numpy.power has no axis argument... is it because there is a better/safer way to achieve the same goal (elevating each 2D array in a 3D array to the power of a 1D array).

Suppose you have a (3,10,10) array (A) and you want to elevate each (10,10) array to the power of elements in array B of shape (3,).
You should be able to do it by using `np.power(A,B,axis=0)`, right? 
Yet it yields the following TypeError :

```
TypeError: 'axis' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'power'
```

Since it seems that power does not have an axis or axes argument (despite being an ufunc), what is the preferred way to do it ?

There may be a solution using the `ufunc.reduce` method but I don't really see how that would work with `numpy.power`...

For now I do :

```
np.array([A[i,:,:]**B[i] for i in range(3)])
```

But it looks ugly and is probably less efficient than a numpy method would be.

Thanks

Comment: You could use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html): `A**B[:,None,None]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`power` is not a *reduction* operation: it does not reduce a collection of numbers to a single number, so an `axis` argument doesn't make sense.  Operations such as `sum` or `max` are reductions, so it is meaningful to specify an axis along which to apply the reduction.

The operation that you want is [*broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  Here's a smaller example, with `A` having shape (3, 2, 2) and `B` having shape `(3,)`.  We can't write `np.power(A, B)`, because the shapes are not compatible for broadcasting.  We first have to add trivial dimensions to `B` to give it the shape (3, 1, 1).  That can be done with, for example, `B[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]` or `B.reshape(-1, 1, 1)`.

```
In [100]: A                                                                                                                                                    
Out[100]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[3, 2],
        [1, 1]],

       [[3, 2],
        [1, 3]]])

In [101]: B                                                                                                                                                    
Out[101]: array([2, 1, 3])

In [102]: np.power(A, B[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])                                                                                                            
Out[102]: 
array([[[ 1,  1],
        [ 9,  9]],

       [[ 3,  2],
        [ 1,  1]],

       [[27,  8],
        [ 1, 27]]])
```

The value of `np.newaxis` is `None`, so you'll often see expressions that use `None` instead of `np.newaxis`.  You can also using the `**` operator instead of the function `power`:

```
In [103]: A ** B[:, None, None]                                                                                                                                
Out[103]: 
array([[[ 1,  1],
        [ 9,  9]],

       [[ 3,  2],
        [ 1,  1]],

       [[27,  8],
        [ 1, 27]]])
```